# Phonegap - Check if File exists

Tags: jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

My problem right now is, I cant check if a file already exists in `Documents Folder` (iOS).
I tried it with ajax and it worked, but I can't use it with the jQuery syntax in my code.

I hope there is a Solution like this:

```
if(fileExists('path/to/file.txt'))
{
    alert('make me happy');
}
else
{
    alert('why u make me sad?');
}
```

I also tried it with

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(fileSource, success, fail);
```

but i need a return, i cant work with a new function.

And using a `FileReader` is crap :/

I hope you can help me find a solution for this.

Comment: What's the problem with using a FileReader ?

Comment: i am going to check multiple files with unkown size, i guess the performance would be bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String.prototype.fileExists = function() {
    filename = this.trim();

    var response = jQuery.ajax({
        url: filename,
        type: 'HEAD',
        async: false
    }).status;  

    return (response != "200") ? false : true;
}
```

Comment: So far it works for me like this:            if(fileSource.fileExists()) i will try out more und give you feedback :)

Comment: There is still some Problem for me, if the File is over 100Mb my App crashes on the iPad. :/